# Photon Networking call many times Service();

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine, photon, photon-pun

According to the following link https://doc.photonengine.com/realtime/current/reference/performance-tips it is recommended to call service() several times, but I wanted to know how many times would be ideal? Because in my app this caused me to exit the game.

```
private void ServiceLoop()
    {
        int timeMill = 20000;
        while (isServiceRunning)
        {
            if (PhotonNetwork.NetworkingClient != null)
            {
                PhotonNetwork.NetworkingClient.Service();

                // if (PhotonNetwork.NetworkingClient.LoadBalancingPeer.SendOutgoingCommands())
                // {
                //     Debug.LogException(new       System.Exception("LoadBalancingPeer.SendOutgoingCommands()"), this);
                //     PhotonNetwork.SendAllOutgoingCommands();
                // }

                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(timeMill);
            }
        }
    }
```

We expected less photon disconnection when calling service() multiple times.

Comment: well this checks its still there, if its not therer then yes your game might end or whatever, so, id expect this is more likely to die when theres been no updates, eg sitting at menus or whatever than if say constantly sending movement.  But if you send too many checks you're wasting band width and enough players and you wont have space for actual data

Comment: We've already tried using ByteArraySlice with raiseEvent according to the link https://doc.photonengine.com/zh-tw/pun/current/gameplay/optimization, but it didn't work well, without many examples on the internet

Answer (score 0):

How many times exactly you should call Service() depends on your game, but usually 10-20 times a second is best.

Your value of 20000 for timeMill is WAY to high. When you don't call it more often than once every 20 seconds, then you are guaranteed to experience a timeout disconnect, as the the server disconnects clients that don't send any life signs for 5-10 seconds and the client only sends from inside of Service() (or rather SendOutgoingCommands(), which is called by Service(), but can alternatively also be called by your code).

Changing the value of timeMill to 100 should fix the issue.